# Are there any standard mechanisms or conventions to prevent Bash environment variable name collisions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, namespaces

This site http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html#PARCHILDPROBREF indicates that a script cannot change its parent's environment variables.

So, (unless the script is sourced) a script cannot accidentally change a coincidentally named environment variable in its parent's environment.

However, namespace collisions can occur if a program relies on environment variables that it declares.

e.g.
suppose I am unaware that vim uses the environment variable name "VIMRUNTIME".  And, by coincidence, I happen to use that environment variable name for my own, unrelated, purposes.  Then vim would get garbage from the VIMRUNTIME environment variable.

Are there any mechanisms or standard, well-known naming conventions to avoid this type of namespace collision?
Of course, I can just do something like naming all my environment variables with some sort of prefix.  But I would like to know if there are any well-known, formal standards for this.  Or, is there some sort of namespace mechanism in Bash that I haven't found?
Suggestions about other, related gotchas are encouraged in comments.

Comment: As you sure know, here are already a bunch of ENV variables like `PATH`, `HOME`, `PAGER`, `EDITOR` and so on. Simply, your environment is yours, and you should know what you're setting. Here is no exact "definition" only usual prefix convention like `LESSCHARSET` or `SSH_CLIENT` or `PERLBREW_HOME`.. etc...

Comment: The best thing to do is to use _lowercase_ variable names in your scripts. Don't follow those people who use uppercase variable names: it's dangerous, ugly, and shows bad taste.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  _Taste cannot be controlled by law._ (Thomas Jefferson) - but otherwise, you're right... ;)

Comment: +1 lowercase vars + prefixing is my choice.

Comment: Your script is unlikely to call vim, is it ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any standard mechanism, other than using a common prefix. For instance, `ssh` uses `SSH_xxx` for all its environment variables. Unfortunately, many legacy programs (e.g. shells) don't follow any kind of convention. And variables that are used across many different programs (e.g. `TERM`, `PAGER`) don't have a program name to use as a prefix.

If you follow the prefixing style, the chance of collision will be small. It's the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't export it. There is a difference between shell variables and environment variables.

Comment: Maybe more of an explanation here would help.